# Why does eigenvalue decomposition of a correlation matrix maximizes possible variance?

Tags: pca, proof

I was reading up on principal component analysis and I was wondering how does eigenvalue decomposition of the correlation matrix maxmimizes the possible variance that is captured? Can someone refer to a proof or give a simple intuitive proof?

Thanks!

Comment: The overal variance is the trace (sum of elements on the diagonal) of the matrix, so with correlation PxP matrix this "variance"=P. PCA (by eigendecomposition or SVD) aims to capture the possible greatest share of the trace - it is how it works, it is its objective function.

Comment: I am wondering if your question was (a) why does eigenvalue decomposition of a covariance matrix maximizes variance (i.e. why do we use eigendecomposition for PCA?), or (b) why does eigenvalue decomposition of **correlation** matrix maximize the **variance** (the answer: it does not, unless one is talking about variance of the standardized variables; then it does)?

Comment: The first one, I'm sorry for the confusion that may have caused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eigendecomposition of a correlation matrix is *one* way to perform PCA. This kind of PCA carries the assumption that each variable contributes exactly one unit of variance to the total variance of the data. So if there are $p$ variables, the eigenvalues will apportion $p$ total units of variance of the data. *Total variance* is thus an abstract concept, unrelated to the variances of the observed variables, unless they all happen to be standardized. (Note: standardization does not affect the eigenvalues here.)

By contrast, the eigendecomposition of a covariance matrix ($\mathbf{\Sigma}$) is another way to perform PCA. The assumption here is that each variable contributes its actual variance (i.e. $s^{2}$) to total variance, and the eigenvalues of such a PCA apportion $\text{trace}(\mathbf{\Sigma})$ total units of variance. Standardization and other transformations of the data will affect the eigenvalues here.